# Incorrect file input c++

Tags: c++, file, random, input

For some reason this code

```
for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    mem[i] = 0;

  //Read input file
  instructions.open (fname.c_str(), fstream::in);
  if (!instructions.is_open() ) {
    std::cout << "Error 404: file not found\n";
    exit (404);
  }

for (i = initial_pos; !instructions.eof(); i++) 
  instructions >> mem[i];
```

is reading this file

```
1
21
1
9
11
9
16
11
9
3
60
2
0
21
0
1
11
4
0
2
2
90
0
```

as such:

```
1
33
1
32
11
0
28
11
1
26
11
2
24
11
3
22
41
1
1
51
8
22
1
3
21
2
0
60
34
12
5
2
2
3
90
0
0
0
1
0
```

Is there any particular reason why the >> operand seems to be adding random numbers to mem? Please note that mem is an initialised array and all the numbers were printed after being read.

Comment: You're using `eof()`, hence your program is broken. About ten other questions today had a very similar problem.

Comment: Your "error 404" may not quite do what you think it does.

Comment: Errors belong on stderr.  Do not use `std::cout`.  That's why `std::cerr` exists.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of writing this the hundredth time, here's how your code *should* be:

```
std::ifstream infile(fname.c_str());   // "in" is implied

if (!infile) { /* error, could not open file */ }

for (int n; infile >> n; )
{
    // we read the number n
}
```

If you just want a container of integers, even better:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile(fname.c_str());
std::istream_iterator<int> beg(infile), end();

std::vector<int> v(beg, end);

// now "v" contains all the integers.
```

Comment: The problem expected us to use a fixed array of integers as the memory. Vectors would increase the chances of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was calling the executable wrong.

It should be:

[ [ [ [input name]]]]

but i was calling it like this:

sim test1.bin

so the simulator was setting the initial PC to "test1.bin" and the input to the default input "input.bin" so i was reading the wrong file.

I guess it always comes down to crappy homework assignment enunciations.